# Parse Unix Command Output in Java

Tags: java, unix, solaris

I am executing the `finger -m` command in Unix. It returns the output as below.

```
Login       Name               TTY         Idle    When    Where
Sam         Sam D S            pts/2            Sun 13:25  10.xxx.xxx.xx
Peter       Peter M Thomas     pts/1         58 Sun 12:25  10.xxx.xxx.xx
```

How do I parse this in a Java program?

There is a space and tab, both combinations, in the output of the command. Also the output produced is not unique with the space and tab as between login and name it returns space but between other its tab.

Is there a way we can display the output which results only tab so we can ignore the space and process.

Comment: Have you considered using regular expressions?

Comment: What do you mean by “parse”?  Can you give an example of the data structure in Java you'd like as a result?  Also, I don't understand this sentence: *“Is there a way we can display the output which results only tab so we can ignore the space and process.”*  Are there chances what you actually want is merely re-style the output, not actually parse it?

Comment: Have you considered reading the raw data from the utmpx file instead of trying to parse the output intended for humans to read and not for programs to parse?

Comment: My data structure looks like LoginId, Name, LoggedInFrom, LoggedDate etc. The command output is in the form of string and i am reading that string. I want to assign Sam to LoginId. Sam D S to Login Name and LoggedInFrom to 10.xx.xxx.xx. How can i do this? Is there a simpler way?.

Comment: Step 1: Normalize your data. In my tests, `finger` does not return any '\t', the output only has spaces, but if you are seeing tabs, pipe the output through `expand` with the right tab size value. Step 2: parse the normalized data using absolute offsets from the beginning of the line to find desired columns. This is not very robust but it should work. I'd read `/var/adm/utmpx` instead just like @alanc suggested.

Comment: Is there a way i can add a pipe char in the output of the finger command after each column. for example                                                 Login|Name|TTY|Idle|When|Where                                          Can we do this for each line of the output. Is it possible with sed command. I tried with this command finger -m | tr -s " " | sed 's/ /| /g' | sed '1 s/, / /g' This is exactly what i wanted but only problem is with the Name if it have first and last name then we have a | between first and last name which is not expected.